# How to get the installed version of GNU Bison

Tags: bison, bisonc++

I'm upgrading from Bison 1.875 to Bison 3.0.4 and want to be backward compatible.

- The function call `yyparse(void *)` works in 1.875, but not in 3.0.4
- The function call `yyparse()` works in 3.04, but not in 1.875

Bison outputs a cpp file, with the line `#define YYBISON_VERSION "3.0.2"`
I used `strcmp` to determine if the actual version is up-to-date and to decide which function call to use:

```
int ret = 0;
if(bisonVersionCheck < 0)
{
    ret = yyparse(void *);
}
else
{
    ret = yyparse();
}
```

But, as you will see, this is determined run-time, so the compiler complains about a function-call he can't do anything with.

I would like to have a macro I can use, so I can use preprocessor directives to select the right function call. I can't find a macro like that in the bison documentation.

- Do someone know about a "__BISON_VERSION"look-a-like-macro?
- Anyone with another idea to do the right function-call based on the bison-version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ret = yyparse(void *)` is not syntactically correct C, regardless of bison version. Perhaps it is not what you meant to type.

It's not clear to me why `yyparse()` doesn't work in your 1.875 code. Perhaps you define the macro `YYPARSE_PARAM` somewhere, in order to add a `void*` argument to `yyparse`. In old versions of bison, that will change the calling convention for `yyparse` but I think it will be ignored by modern versions. See the declaration `℅parse-param` for a replacement, if needed (although the question seems to imply that the argument to `yyparse` is not used).